PHP Codeigniter 4 redirect route not found after insert
I have a controller that calls my model to insert a new record, returned the id of the new record, and then does a redirect to display the new record.  But I get an error: "The route for '/r/xx' cannot be found".  My Routes.php has a route:
 $routes->get("/r/(:num)", "Home::showRec/$1");

The controller code:
   $rid = $mymodel->mSaveNew($data);  ##return correct new id
   if ($rid === false) {
       $this->session->setFlashdata('errors', "?system error adding new record");
   } else {
       $this->session->setFlashdata('messages', "*** Added new record #$rid");
   }
   return redirect("/r/$rid");  ### this fails ###

What is wrong with my route?
The same redirect() route called in another controller method for updating an existing record works fine.

is $rid returned as expected? a number?

Yes it has a non-zero value; in my last test, "The route for '/r/88' cannot be found."

I should mention: This controller method is the one that handles an Add New request (saveNewRec).  The routes are:
$routes->get('/a', 'Home::addRec');
$routes->post('/a', 'Home::saveNewRec');

have you tried this? return redirect()->to("/r/$rid");

The redirect() function operates differently in CI4 which @shirshak007 comment above makes reference too. You are using the CI3 style but you need the ->to() bit as well in CI4.

Thanks so much!  It is the ->to() method that works.  Seems I need to read more about CI4 differences (been in CI3 too long).
